# Is it worthwhile investing time learning Unreal Script when UDK 4 will be replacing it with C++?

Tags: udk, unreal

Should I continue to get more familiar with Unreal Script or just wait for UDK4 with C++?

Comment: If you aren't even that deep into the scripting language, why bother when the new system goes with C++? You need to look forward right?

Comment: If it's "worth it" or not is entirely subjective to you. If you think it's a waste of your time to learn something and only have something new come out, then I think you need to switch to a slower moving industry. You'll be sorely disappointed by almost anything computer related.

Comment: there are always going to be new systems and programming languages.  All that matters is that you are able to make an end product (game, engine, or whatever).

Comment: I have seen no indication that UDK4 will replace Unreal Script with C++. It would be a very stupid thing to do, since you’d need a compiler for every architecture supported by UDK4. What are your sources?

Answer (score 8):

I don't understand the question. When will the UDK4 be out? One year, *at the least*? Plus, you'll have to wait for it to become stable enough to reasonably use.

The question you *should* ask is, "Do I want to make a game?" If the answer is "yes," then you should use the tools you have *available* to do so. There will always be some new tool coming in a couple of years. If you want to get something *done*, that means picking your tech and sticking with it.

Plus, if new tech comes along and actually *exists* that you like more, you can always switch to it.

Comment: +1 for everything here, though often if you're a year or more down the track with a project, it's usually not such a simple task to just switch technologies especially when there's something as fundamental as a completely new language involved.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should learn both. I agree with Matt that you can run into a lot of difficulty swapping out technologies mid-project. That being said it might be helpful for you to learn a scripting language as well as a high-level language like C++. Scripting languages are very valuable because they can be accessible enough for designers to use for game logic as well as being faster because the ease of reloading the code without having to recompile.

Hope this helps.